# I get "Truncated incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00'" even with Strict mode off

Tags: mysql, database

I have disabled the strict mode in my conf file by setting `sql-mode=""` and restarted the machine, but I still get the error, after I run the query. Altering the table is not possible or desired.

I use WAMP for Windows. What could potentially cause SQL to throw this error besides the sql mode? After I run `SELECT @@sql_mode;` it returns correctly empty value

EDIT: I use mysql version 5.7.19

Comment: How can we reproduce the same  issue ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Of course the issue is not reproduceable, I would have to give you whole sql dump, since giving the query without context will not help at all. I was thinking someone could have general idea what could cause it

Comment: MySQL version can be helpful, since there were multiple changes in default values in the last few releases: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before:

All i did is, Removed the Default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  as set by `timestamp` datatype and replace to `datetime` Datatype.

All 0000:00:00 is gone.

Comment: As I said, altering the database in any way, even changing the datatype is not possible in current project